# Unable to get the data to next activity

Tags: android

I am trying to get the data to next activity using Bundle and putString. But the data fail to carry to the next page. Below is part of my coding:

```
public class assessment_table_edit extends AppCompatActivity {
Toolbar toolbar;
String data = "";
TableLayout tlAssessment;
TableRow tr;
TextView stuID,totalmarks,marks,edit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_assessment_table_edit);
    toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Percentage of the Marks");
    tlAssessment=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tlAssessment_Edit);


    final Assessment_Information_GetData getdb=new Assessment_Information_GetData();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            data =getdb.getDataFromDB();
            System.out.println(data);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ArrayList<Assessment_Information> users=parseJSON(data);
                    addData(users);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();


    if(getSupportActionBar()!=null){
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}

View.OnClickListener onClickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.assessment_id:
                Assessment_Information user=new Assessment_Information();
                Intent iChange=new Intent(assessment_table_edit.this,assessment_edit_data.class);
                Bundle b=new Bundle();
                b.putString("stuID",user.getStuID());
                iChange.putExtras(b);
               // iChange.putExtra("stuID",user.getStuID());
                startActivity(iChange);
                break;
        }
    }
};


public ArrayList<Assessment_Information>parseJSON(String result){
    ArrayList<Assessment_Information> users=new ArrayList<Assessment_Information>();
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(result);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("posts");
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_data = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Assessment_Information user=new Assessment_Information();
            user.setStuID(json_data.getString("stuID"));
            user.setTotalmarks(json_data.getString("totalmarks"));
            user.setMarks(json_data.getString("marks"));
            users.add(user);
        }

    }catch (JSONException e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return users;
}
```

When I replace user.getString() to "check" for testing, it managed to show in the next activity(assessment_edit_data). 
This is assessment_edit_data.java:

```
public class assessment_edit_data extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tvMatrix;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_assessment_edit_data);
        tvMatrix=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.edit_data_assessment);
        Bundle bundle=getIntent().getExtras();
        String stuID=bundle.getString("stuID");
        tvMatrix.setText(stuID);

    }
```

My Assessment_Information.java:

```
public class Assessment_Information {
    String stuID;
    String totalmarks;
    String marks;

    public String getStuID() {
        return stuID;
    }

    public void setStuID(String stuID) {
        this.stuID = stuID;
    }

    public String getTotalmarks() {
        return totalmarks;
    }

    public void setTotalmarks(String totalmarks) {
        this.totalmarks = totalmarks;
    }

    public String getMarks() {
        return marks;
    }

    public void setMarks(String marks) {
        this.marks = marks;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the 2 classes (activities)? I think there's not enough info here.

Comment: You may is passing stuID, but it's empty, are you sure stuID has value?

Comment: I have updated.

Comment: @guisantogui yes, I managed to fetch the value, but when I click Edit to next activity, it shows nothing

Comment: The code to setting the string and retrieving it looks ok. Try putting some logs and also try with a hardcoded string..

Comment: I have tried hardcoded string and I managed to get the data. So it mean my code is working good. Just problem with user.getStuID(); i guess

Comment: Just debug it step by step. I recommend using breakpoints to visualise data and what's happening. Also make sure that you call setStuID(String stuID) and retrieve data from the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to send data to another activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", "value");
intent.putExtra("key2", "value2");
startActivity(intent);
```

And use this code to get the data in the other Activity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if(bundle!=null){
    String value1 = bundle.getString("key");
    String value2 = bundle.getString("key2");
}
```

You can check if your bundle contains the key:

```
if(bundle.containsKey("key")){
   //...
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

You're creating a new user without any data (it seems)

```
Assessment_Information user=new Assessment_Information(); //This user has data?
Intent iChange=new Intent(assessment_table_edit.this,assessment_edit_data.class);
Bundle b=new Bundle();
b.putString("stuID",user.getStuID()); // user.getStuID() probably is null
```

I don't see in your class `Assessment_Information` a constructor where you insert data to the `stuID` variable.

---

**UPDATE**

Try this part of code:

```
public class assessment_table_edit extends AppCompatActivity {
    Toolbar toolbar;
    String data = "";
    TableLayout tlAssessment;
    TableRow tr;
    TextView stuID,totalmarks,marks,edit;
    ArrayList<Assessment_Information> users;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_assessment_table_edit);
        toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Percentage of the Marks");
        tlAssessment=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tlAssessment_Edit);


        final Assessment_Information_GetData getdb=new Assessment_Information_GetData();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                data =getdb.getDataFromDB();
                System.out.println(data);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        users=parseJSON(data);
                        addData(users);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start();


        if(getSupportActionBar()!=null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    View.OnClickListener onClickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.assessment_id:

                    Intent iChange=new Intent(assessment_table_edit.this,assessment_edit_data.class);
                    Bundle b=new Bundle();
                    b.putString("stuID", users.get(0).getStuID());

                    // If you want to send more than the first user
                    //for(int i=0; users.size() < i ; i++) {
                    //    b.putString("stuID"+i, users.get(i).getStuID());
                    //}
                    //b.putInt("numberOfUsers", users.size());

                    iChange.putExtras(b);
                    // iChange.putExtra("stuID",user.getStuID());
                    startActivity(iChange);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks, but the data able to retrieve from database. So probably not null.

Comment: But you are using a new user, if you have the data in another place, you have to add this data to the new user using the setter setStuId()

Comment: Or if you have a user with the data, use the previous user with the data and do not create a new one.

Comment: Thanks, now I am able to get the data. But why it only get one fixed data? Is it because users.get(0)? . I want it to be when i click Edit for No Matrix bi14110104 it will shows data for this user, and when i click other users, it will show the details of the user. But now it fixed to one user.

Comment: I want to get every user details when I click Edit :(

Comment: Then try to use the commented code, you should create an extra for every user.

Comment: "// If you want to send more than the first user ", is this code can be used? Because this is what I want.

Comment: Yes. Remember to get all the extras in the new activity too.

Comment: Thanks, i will try. Thanks for your answer. Can I ask you here if anything?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159985/discussion-between-kleorence-and-marcgv).

Answer (score 1):

The problem it is you instantiate the user object but never retrieve the data. The user is as you declared it in the class. 
At least you should read the data from you db and set it to the new object.

Answer (score 0):

This is right way to `putExtra` and `getExtra` some data in Android.

Use this to "put" the file...

```
Intent i = new Intent(FirstScreen.this, SecondScreen.class);   
String strName = null;
i.putExtra("STRING_I_NEED", strName);
```

Then, to retrieve the value try something like:

```
String newString;

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras == null) {
    newString= null;
} else {
    newString= extras.getString("STRING_I_NEED");
}
```

**Bonus Suggestion :**
I can see your class name is `assessment_edit_data`.
Make it like `AssessmentEditData` as Java suggest naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Kleorence,

**I was shocked to see your huge code for adding a new row.** I am giving you my code to add a new row with your desired `styles and themes.`

**Pros:**

- Just code in .xml as you always do.
- No need to code in java for styling rows.

  ```
  in onCreate 

  TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tlpromote);

  private void addNewRow() {
  // instantiate a tableRow
      TableRow row = new TableRow(context);
  // inflate your custom view on it.
      View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.table_row, row, false);
  // put your values in its views
      TextView tvTable_sr = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTable_sr);
      TextView tvTable_title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTable_title);
  //add your custom view to row
      tableLayout.addView(v);
  }
  ```

Here `table_row` is your row with custom view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!--make any view you want-->

</LinearLayout>
```

*I hope you find this very helpful.*

Comment: Thanks for the suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are populating the data in an array but when passing the object to another activity, you are creating a brand-new object in which every field is null.

```
public class assessment_table_edit extends AppCompatActivity {
Toolbar toolbar;
String data = "";
TableLayout tlAssessment;
TableRow tr;
TextView stuID,totalmarks,marks,edit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_assessment_table_edit);
    toolbar=(Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Percentage of the Marks");
    tlAssessment=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tlAssessment_Edit);

//You are populating data here.
    final Assessment_Information_GetData getdb=new Assessment_Information_GetData();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            data =getdb.getDataFromDB();
            System.out.println(data);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ArrayList<Assessment_Information> users=parseJSON(data);
                    addData(users);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();


    if(getSupportActionBar()!=null){
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}



   View.OnClickListener onClickListener=new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()){
                case R.id.assessment_id:
//Creating a new user in which every field is null/null object.
                    Assessment_Information user=new Assessment_Information();
                    Intent iChange=new Intent(assessment_table_edit.this,assessment_edit_data.class);
                    Bundle b=new Bundle();
//Passing an a field from the null object.
                        b.putString("stuID",user.getStuID());
                        iChange.putExtras(b);
                       // iChange.putExtra("stuID",user.getStuID());
                        startActivity(iChange);
                        break;
                }
            }
        };
```

Try MarcGV's answer, or some variation of it to get some data.